# Replace Powershell 5.1 with Powershell core 7

Tags: windows-10, powershell

We want to update our powershell version to core 7, but due to old, absurd security rules, we cannot use the MSI. We have set up dotnet 5 successfully using the zip and can now run powershell 7 successfully. However, we would like to replace 5.1 completely with 7.

Registry is complaining that it cannot change the the contents of the powershell command so we cannot change it there. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: you cannot do that. ps5.1 is REQUIRED by win10 for some things. [*grin*] you can, however, install the newer versions side-by-side - that is the default. old version = `powershell.exe` & new version = `pwsh.exe`.

Comment: As per Microsoft. you can never replace Windows PowerShell. It's part of the OS, included with .Net full (again, part of the OS), and PowerShell Core (which uses .Net Core) is not part of the OS as it is an Open Source cross-platform product.